# Is Varivasya Rahasyam avaliable as online pdf?

Tags: resource, sri-vidya

I am unable to find Varivasya Rahasyam online pdf. Appreciate if someone can point online or give link for a good printed book.

Comment: There are many books with the name Setubandh. Which book are you looking for? Please remember that only one question is to be asked per post. For Sertubandh, ask a new question with details who is the author and which language you are looking for.

Comment: Related post - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19557/who-was-sri-vidya-guru-pujyasri-bhaskara-raya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varivasya Rahasya is available on archive.org. English translation by Pandit S Subrahmanya Sastri.

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.202793

It can be downloaded in different formats with pdf included.